# Iterating over Facebook Graph API data in Ruby

Tags: ruby, facebook-graph-api

Figured this out on my own -- code at the bottom (needed to raise an exception because a couple of the strings I had were invalid).

I've been having an issue in that I keep getting a 400 error when I run the following code.  I've spot checked individual values and they all seem to work, and I can get this to run fine with just one value in my posts array (which has about 350 values right now).  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
require 'open-uri'
require 'JSON'

posts = [blahblah1, blahblah2... blahblah350]

api_key = "REALLYLONGSTRING"

output = File.open("facebook-posts.csv", "w+")

posts.each do |post|
    obj = JSON.parse(open("https://graph.facebook.com/v2.3/#{post.to_s}?access_token=#{api_key}").read)
    output << obj
    output << "\n"
end

output.close
```

Working code:

```
posts.each do |post|
    begin
    obj = JSON.parse(open("https://graph.facebook.com/v2.3/#{post.to_s}?access_token=#{api_key}").read)
    rescue OpenURI::HTTPError
        next
    end
    output << obj
    output << "\n"
```

Comment: Do you have a line number of log statement explaining why you get a 400? Can you give the exact url, without variables but exact values, that you call? (please do not paste your access token).

Comment: The line that gives me the 400 error is the JSON.parse line, and an example of a URL is:
    https://graph.facebook.com/v2.3/#10153017672300801?access_token=#

Comment: The above URL is wrong -- sorry, it's  
graph.facebook.com/v2.3/10153017672300801?access_token=#